# How to add python modules that are not picked up by pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a little project, that depends on a git submodule that have a python module and some scripts.
Now I like to use pyInstaller to create a package. But it fails to pickup the submodule.

My folder struct looks like:

```
myFancyGUI.py
fancy/ << my git submodule
fancy/fancy/__init__.py << the python fancy module
fancy/fancy/fancy.py 
fancy/scripts/everythingFancy.py << a script not part of the fancy module, but used by the fancy GUI and its using the fancy.py to get its stuff done
```

pyinstaller has problems to resolve the fancy module as well as the everythingFancy.py

Any ideas how to alter the spec script to make pyInstaller to include and resolve the fancy python modules/files?